# Best way to ensure an initial network request is completed before other requests are sent (iOS app)

Tags: ios, swift, networking

An app I am working on requires creating a container object on a server and inserting items into that container. I don't want to create the container object until the first item needs to be inserted. However, creating the container object requires some initialization that may take a little time. While that container is still initializing the user can still to send insertion requests that aren't getting handled because the container isn't ready yet. I have two main questions:

1. Should this be dealt with on the client or server side?
2. What is the best practice for dealing with kind of this issue?

Essentially, I need to ensure my initial `createContainer` data task in complete before any `insertItem` requests are sent.

**Addition Information**

An `insertItem` request is sent by clicking on a corresponding `tableViewCell`. The first `tableViewCell` a user clicks on sends a `createContainer` request that creates a container holding the first item.

For a container holding *n* items, the request should be sent in the following order:

- `createContainer(Container(with: item1)`
- `insertItem(item2)`
- ...
- `insertItem(item`*n*`)`

After the first request completes, the remaining *n* – 1 requests may complete in any order.

**My Thoughts**

It sounds like I want the `createContainer` request to be handled synchronously while the `insertItem` request should be handled asynchronously. I'm not sure if that is the best approach or even how to perform that appropriately, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `NSOperationQueue` and multiple `NSOperation`s to implement your desired behavior. A `NSOperation` instance can be dependent on the completion of another `NSOperation` instance:

> dependencies
>
> An array of the operation objects that must finish
>   executing before the current object can begin executing.

For your example this would mean that the `insertItem`-Operations are dependent on the `createContainer` operation.

When you add all those operations to a `NSOperationQueue` your `createContainer` operation will run first. When it has finished, the other operations will start running as their dependencies are now satisfied. You can also control how many operations you want to run concurrently using `maxConcurrentOperationCount` on `NSOperationQueue`.

As you will be using asynchronous API in your `NSOperation`s you will need to implement a `ConcurrentOperation` and handle the state changes yourself. The API Reference is explaining this in pretty good detail.

Check out the [API Reference for NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation) for further information.
There is also a nice [NSHipster article on NSOperations](http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/).

Comment: While this answer did lead me to the solution I needed, it did not quite fit my use case. It turns out that when a `createContainer` request is started–but before the response comes back–the user initiates more `insertItem` requests, which require `createContainer` to have completed. OperationQueues are required, but the dependency has to be handled differently.
Anyone else looking for a description of this use case, please see [this article](http://www.oded-tech-blog.com/ios-swift-how-to-wait-for-async-network-call-in-nsoperation/).

Comment: I think you should implement a Concurrent operation instead of using semaphors. See this gist on how to do that: https://gist.github.com/calebd/93fa347397cec5f88233

Concurrent operations require you to handle the state changes manually. You would set the state to `.finished` once the network request is finished. This way you can use `NSOperations` to manage dependencies for network requests.

Comment: I see, this is certainly a better solution. Would I then make `createContainer` a `ConcurrentOperation` and let `insertItem`s be traditional `Operation`s since I don't need to track anything after `createContainer` is finished? Would I then put those operations in the same `OperationQueue`? Will this [Swift 3 version](https://gist.github.com/alexaubry/1ee81a952b11a2ddc6a43480cc59032c) of `ConcurrentOperation` behave the same?

Comment: Wether you should use a `ConcurrentOperation` or not does not depend on whether you want to do something after the operation is finished. It depends on whether the API you are using inside your operation is asynchronous itself (like network requests). For anything that is synchronous `ConcurrentOperation` **will also work** but you do not really need the added complexity. Just use a regular `NSOperation` and implement `- main`. Yes, in your case you should add your operations to the same `OperationQueue`.

Comment: The Swift 3 version you linked to seems to work fine. I can also recommend [PSOperations](https://github.com/pluralsight/PSOperations/tree/master/PSOperations) for some advanced additions. I would not add it just for `ConcurrentOperation`s but if you need the additional features (for example `GroupOperation`), it might be a nice addition.

Comment: Awesome, that all makes sense. Just to clarify, in the case of `insertItem` requests, I don't mind the associated operation completing before the `dataTask` itself, which is why I don't think I should bother making them `ConcurrentOperations`. The `createContainer` request is the only one that needs to post `.finished` when the `dataTask` is complete. Does that sound reasonable?
Thanks so much, you've been a huge help

Comment: No. If your task works by using an asynchronous API you should use a `ConcurrentOperation`. Whenever an operation is finished it will be removed from the `OperationQueue` and deallocated (if there is no reference to it anymore). This *might* lead to issues with your `dataTask`.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'm a little confused about how to get the dependency I want. I need to be sure that no `insertItem` operations start before the `createContainer` operation finishes. My understanding is that all operations that are ready will start as soon as they are added to an `OperationQueue`. I get that using a `ConcurrentOperation` gives me control of state changes, but I don't yet see how that helps with my ordering problem. How do I keep the `insertItem` operations from starting prematurely? (These operations are user initiated, so I cannot use the `addDependency` method.)

Comment: At the moment my problem is that clicking multiple `tableViewCell`s in quick succession produces a `createContainer` request followed by, say, four `insertItem` requests. Depending of how long `createContainer` takes, one or two of those `insertItem` requests might complete before a container is ever created, but those items can't get added to a nonexistent container.

Comment: Why can't you use `addDependeny`?

Comment: Another way might be to set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to one so you get a serial queue. Then, be sure to add your `createContainer` operation first.

Comment: Still, you should be able to use `addDependency`, user initiated or not.

Comment: In all of the examples of using `addDependencey` I've seen there are a fixed number of operations established, and then some of those operations are added as dependencies of others before all of them are added to the queue. In my case I don't how many `insertItem` requests there will be or even if the `createContainer` operation would even still exist to add as a dependency.

Comment: In other words, I'm not going to create all of the `insertItem` operations I need before I add them all to the queue. I would be adding the `createContainer` operation first, then adding the `insertItem` operations to the queue as they come up. I'm not sure at what point in that process I would make `insertItem` depend on `createContainer`.

Comment: In the Concurrency Programming Guide, Apple says, "You should always configure dependencies before running your operations or adding them to an operation queue. Dependencies added afterward may not prevent a given operation object from running." This is where I feel my use case differs. I am unable to configure the necessary dependencies before I add my operations to the queue.

Comment: No you are not. Simply `addDependency` on your `insertItem` operations **before you add those** to the queue. If you do you that, you respect the Concurrency Programming Guide because you are configuring the dependencies of `insertItem` before you add it to the queue. 
Basically you have to 
 - Create a new `insertItem` operation
 - Check whether `createContainer` is still running (by using a instance variable or going through the queue)
 - If it does, add it as a dependency
 - Add your `insertItem` operation to the queue

Comment: Remember, you can always just use a serial queue and not worry about dependencies as long as you add the operations in the right order.

Comment: In order to check that the `createContainer` operation is complete you suggest using an instance variable. Could that just be an instance variable on the same class as my `OperationQueue` (e.g. something like a flag `var isContainerReady: Bool` that becomes true once `createContainer` is complete)? Checking the contents of the queue every time just feels a little clunky to me. If I go down the serial queue route, would I change the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1 and once `createContainer` completes change it back to whatever it was before so that `insertItem` operations run concurrently?

Comment: This was extremely helpful, I really appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the **NSOperationQueue** answer, it's sometimes difficult to manually manage all the **state changes** that an NSOperation requires to handle something asynchronous like a network call.

To simplify that, you can use a Swift Library called [Overdrive](https://github.com/arikis/Overdrive). It's an amazing library in which you simply subclass a *Task* class and write your network code in the **run()** function. And when you're done, you simply call **self.finish** to finish the task. Here's an example: Just create a simple download task:

[image: Simple Image Download Task]

Then, just add it to the queue.

[image]

You can also add dependencies between tasks, which basically solves your use case.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of good information. Should definitely help, thanks for your contribution.